# Are there any graph\chart packages for WPF good for for electrical signals and waveforms?

Tags: wpf, graph, package

I need functions like:

1. zooming, dragging screen, moving curves in relation to other curves
2. an ability to draw rectangle "corridor" and see if curve is between top and bottom of that corridor
3. having to vertical lines ("grippers") and see their intersection with chosen curves. Or see if manually chosen point on "grippers" is less than in set range proximity from chosen curve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without other suggestions I guess I'll have to stick with OxyPlot. It seems to provide an ability to visualize those options, some with heavy effort.